# force loading completion function for zsh (without forcing its execution by hitting tab)

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I want to replace an existing zsh completion function and keep a reference to the original [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774538/override-a-shell-function-keep-a-reference-to-the-original-one). E.g. to make tab completion always suggest `nice` as first word in a command line:

```
eval "$(declare -f _normal | sed '1s/.*/_original&/')"
_normal() {
  if [[ $CURRENT == 1 ]] ; then
    # suggest only "nice" as first word
    _wanted commands expl "be nice" compadd nice
  else
    # do normal completion afterwards
    _original_normal
  fi
}
```

The problem, as far as I understand it right now, is that in a fresh zsh `_normal` is not loaded yet:

```
PROMPT> functions _normal
_normal () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
```

yet, after I hit ⇥ for the first time, it is loaded:

```
PROMPT> functions _normal
_normal () {
    local _comp_command1 _comp_command2 _comp_command skip
    if [[ "$1" = -s ]]
    then
        skip=(-s) 
    else
        skip=() 
        _compskip='' 
 <snap>
```

This means the above redefinition of `_normal` cannot be done in my .zshrc, as only the `builtin autoload` bit gets written to `_original_normal` which then cannot get loaded (no file `_original_normal` in the `fpath`).

Is there a way how I can force loading `_normal`?

PS: It appears doing the redefinition of `_normal` works if I do it in a shell after hitting tab before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh, you can pass the `+X` flag to `autoload` to load a function from `$fpath` without executing it.

Also, you can copy a function to a new name by manipulating the `functions` array.

```
autoload -Uz +X _normal
functions[_original_normal]=$functions[_normal]
_normal () {
  …
}
```

Comment: @GAD3R ??? “Zsh” isn't code, it's the name of a piece of software (a proper noun, but like many names of software, not normally capitalized).

Answer (score 0):

for now I run

```
_normal &> /dev/null || true
```

`_normal` like other completions should usually not be called from the shell directly and (without the redirection) one gets an error message:

> _default:compcall:12: can only be called from completion function

the `|| true` seems unnecessary here, as `_normal` invoked like this doesn't return an error code.