# overwrite and reuse existing function in zsh

Tags: zsh, function

I would like to slightly extend a zsh completion function.

I would like to avoid putting the complete function body into my homedir with only one line changed. Instead I would like to intercept it's call and then call the original function myself. In quasi code:

```
<make sure _the_original_function is loaded>
_backup_of_original_function=_the_original_function

_the_original_function() {
   _arguments "-superduper[that one option I always need]"
   _backup_of_originial_function $@
}
```

In my concrete case, I have an cmake property in practically all my projects such that I would like to modify the cmake completion. Not having that option in the completion would annoy me much more than having it in projects where the option does not belong. So instead of copying `_cmake` somewhere I would just redefine `_cmake_define_common_property_names()` in my `.zshrc`:

```
_cmake_define_common_property_names() {
  local properties; properties=(
    'MY_GREAT_OPTION:be awesome'
  )                    

  _describe -t 'my-property-names' 'my property name' properties $@

  **call original _cmake_define_common_property_names here
}
```

So what's missing is loading `_cmake_define_common_property_names` and assigning a new function name to it.

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335868) I tried

```
autoload -Uz +X _cmake_define_common_property_names
```

but this fails (the function is not defined within its own file, but rather in `_cmake`.

NB: I don't assign a new function name to avoid having to modify the place from where the function gets called in its original version.

What works partially is `autoload -Uz +X _cmake` BUT this only ensures that `_cmake` is loaded (which I verify by calling `functions _cmake`). It does not load the helper function `_cmake_define_common_property_names`.

So my two questions are

1. how do I load a function from within an `$fpath` file
2. Once I have a function loaded. How do I copy it in a script / Assign a new function name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### How to patch a function

The code of a function is stored in the associative array `functions`. That's the source code with normalized whitespace and no comments (zsh has done lexical analysis and pretty-prints the tokens). You can change the code of a function by modifying the entry of the `functions` array. For example, to add extra code at the beginning:

```
functions[_cmake_define_common_property_names]="
    … # your extra code here
    $functions[_cmake_define_common_property_names]"
```

If the changes you want to make only involve running code before and after the original code (or more generally around, e.g. to put it inside a conditional), you can copy the function to a new name and redefine the function to call that new name. Since zsh 5.8, you can do this easily with [`functions -c`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-functions-1).

```
functions -c _cmake_define_common_property_names _cmake_define_common_property_names_orig
_cmake_define_common_property_names () {
    …
    _cmake_define_common_property_names_orig "$@"
}
```

Alternatively, in any version of zsh, you can also use the `functions` array to copy a function to another name.

```
functions[_cmake_define_common_property_names_orig]=$functions[_cmake_define_common_property_names]
_cmake_define_common_property_names () {
    …
    _cmake_define_common_property_names_orig "$@"
}
```

#### Loading all the functions

The only sure-fire way to load all the functions from a file made for autoload is to execute the function, if you can arrange to execute it with no side effects. For a completion function, just run the function with errors redirected to the bit bucket. It'll do nothing but complain that it isn't being executed in a completion context.

```
_cmake 2>/dev/null
# Now _cmake_xxx is defined
```

The reason `autoload -Uz +X _cmake` doesn't work is that the definitions of the auxiliary functions are in the `_cmake` function itself.

```
% echo $functions[_cmake]
builtin autoload -XU
% autoload -Uz +X _cmake
% echo $functions[_cmake]
…
        (( $+functions[_cmake_define_property_names] )) || _cmake_define_property_names () {
…
}
…
        local cmake_command_actions
        cmake_command_actions=('-E[CMake command mode]:*:command') 
        _cmake_command () {
                _arguments -C -s - command "$cmake_command_actions[@]"
        }
        local cmake_suggest_build
        cmake_suggest_build=('--build[build]') 
        if [ $CURRENT -eq 2 ]
        then
                _arguments -C -s - help "$cmake_help_actions[@]" - command "$cmake_command_actions[@]" - build_opts "$cmake_build_options[@]" - build_cmds "$cmake_suggest_build[@]" && return 0
        elif [[ $words[2] = --help* ]]
        then
                _cmake_help
        elif [[ $words[2] != -E ]]
        then
                _cmake_on_build
        else
                _cmake_command
        fi
```

If you really don't want to execute the toplevel function, you have several choices:

- Patch the definition of `_cmake_define_common_property_names` inside the definition of `_cmake`.
- Extract the definition of `_cmake_define_common_property_names` from the definition of `_cmake` and use that to define `_cmake_define_common_property_names_orig` or `_cmake_define_common_property_names`.
- Patch the definition of `_cmake` to remove the parts other than the function definitions, then execute it. It isn't really workable with `_cmake`, but some other completion functions are better structured. For example `_cvs` consists purely of conditional function definitions (e.g. `(( $+functions[_cvs_command] )) || _cvs_command () { … }`), a definition of the titular function, and a call of the titular function as the very last thing, thus you can define all the function but not execute anything by removing the last line.

  ```
    autoload -Uz +X _cvs
    functions[_cvs]=${functions_cvs%'$\n'*}
    _cvs
    # Patch auxiliary functions here
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I may have put the things together too carelessly but got a few errors `_tags:comptags:60: nesting level too deep`. Which I fixed by putting the creation of the `_orig` functions into an "only if backup not yet made" block:

`(( $+functions[_cmake_define_property_names_orig] )) || functions[_cmake_define_property_names_orig]=$functions[_cmake_define_property_names]`

Comment: `functions -c <old> <new>` is a slightly more compact way to copy a function.

Comment: @ak2 Indeed, thanks (it didn't exist when I posted this answer).