# How to extend existing zsh completion functions?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to add auto-completion for some custom ant parameters. However, it seems to be overwriting the existing oh my zsh ant plugin auto-completions which I'd like to keep. Is there a simple way to have both the oh my zsh plugin and my custom ant auto-completion live in harmony?

Here's the existing plugin at `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/ant/ant.plugin.zsh`

```
_ant_does_target_list_need_generating () {
  [ ! -f .ant_targets ] && return 0;
  [ build.xml -nt .ant_targets ] && return 0;
  return 1;
}

_ant () {
  if [ -f build.xml ]; then
    if _ant_does_target_list_need_generating; then
        ant -p | awk -F " " 'NR > 5 { print lastTarget }{lastTarget = $1}' > .ant_targets
    fi
    compadd -- `cat .ant_targets`
  fi
}

compdef _ant ant
```

And my auto complete at `~/my_completions/_ant`

```
#compdef ant

_arguments '-Dprop=-[properties file]:filename:->files' '-Dsrc=-[build directory]:directory:_files -/'
case "$state" in
    files)
        local -a property_files
        property_files=( *.properties )
        _multi_parts / property_files
        ;;
esac
```

And here is my `$fpath`, the path for my completion is earlier in the list which I guess is why my script gets precedence.

```
/Users/myusername/my_completions /Users/myusername/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git /Users/myusername/.oh-my-zsh/functions /Users/myusername/.oh-my-zsh/completions /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/5.0.8/functions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to extend completion function. Here is how you can do it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450133

First you would need to find the name of your existing function, to do it, you can bind `_complete_help` to CTRL-h (or any other shortcut), then type your command and look for completion function. Here is an example running it for git:

```
% bindkey '^h' _complete_help  
% git [press ctrl-h]
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-1 options  (_arguments _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git:argument-1:
    aliases main-porcelain-commands user-commands third-party-commands ancillary-manipulator-commands ancillary-interrogator-commands interaction-commands plumbing-manipulator-commands plumbing-interrogator-commands plumbing-sync-commands plumbing-sync-helper-commands plumbing-internal-helper-commands  (_git_commands _git)
```

In this case the completion function is `_git`.
Next you can redefine it in your `.zshrc` like this:

```
# Call the function to make sure that it is loaded.
_git 2>/dev/null
# Save the original function.
functions[_git-orig]=$functions[_git]
# Redefine your completion function referencing the original.
_git() {
    _git-orig "$@"
    ...
}
```

You wouldn't need to call `compdef` again, since it is already bound to that function, and you just changed the function definition.

Comment: nice tip on finding the original function and the proper syntax to override it, will give it a go :)