# Define git aliases based on gitconfig in zsh

Tags: zsh, git

I have the following lines in my `~/.aliases`:

```bsh
function __function_exists() {
    declare -f -F $1 > /dev/null
    return $?
}

# git aliases (need to have git bash completion installed)
for al in `__git_aliases`; do
    alias g$al="git $al"

    complete_func=_git_$(__git_aliased_command $al)
    __function_exists $complete_fnc && __git_complete g$al $complete_func
done
```

And in my `~/.gitconfig` i have:

```
[alias]
    # one-line log
    l = log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %ad%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --date=short

    a = add
    ap = add -p
    c = commit --verbose
    ca = commit -a --verbose
    cm = commit -m
    cam = commit -a -m
    m = commit --amend --verbose

    d = diff
    ds = diff --stat
    dc = diff --cached

    s = status -s
    co = checkout
    cob = checkout -b
    # list branches sorted by last modified
    b = "!git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate' --format='%(authordate)%09%(objectname:short)%09%(refname)' refs/heads | sed -e 's-refs/heads/--'"

    # list aliases
    la = "!git config -l | grep alias | cut -c 7-"
```

And in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/giuliani/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
[[ -f $HOME/.aliases ]] && source "$HOME/.aliases"
```

So, for each alias in my gitconfig i will define a shell alias like `gl` for `git log` and so on.

Trying to port this to zsh i'm having a problem: zsh `autoload` built-in only loads the file `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git` the first time i try to complete some git command.

I've tried to call/load `_git` file directly from the `.zshrc` but other them a few warnings, it didn't work.

What is the proper way to have the same funcionality that i have in bash, using zsh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, calling `_git` from your `.zshrc` does work, in that it defines `_git` and its companion functions including `__git_aliases`, and it tries to do some completion but fails (without even an error message in this particular case). [This works with most completion functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450043/overwrite-and-reuse-existing-function-in-zsh/450133#450133). You need to do this after `compinit` so that `_git` and its auxiliary functions are marked for autoloading.

```
% zsh -f
darkstar% autoload compinit          
darkstar% compinit
darkstar% _git 
darkstar% __git_aliases 
_tags:comptags:36: can only be called from completion function
_tags:comptry:55: can only be called from completion function
_tags:comptags:60: can only be called from completion function
_tags:comptags:67: can only be called from completion function
```

The problem is that when you run `__git_aliases`, it calls builtins that can only be used while doing completion. You can work around that by temporarily defining functions with the same name as these builtins that do just the part that you want to do, which is often nothing, but it is very clumsy. I'm not going to show how because there's a much simpler way in this particular case.

Since you're diving deep into the `_git` completion file anyway, call `__git_extract_aliases` instead of `__git_aliases`. `__git_extract_aliases` stuffs information into the variable `aliases` in a way that's easy to extract. (Note: I wrote this answer for zsh 5.4.2, which is the version on Ubuntu 18.04. Other versions of zsh may have different structure in `_git`.)

```sh
_git 2>/dev/null
define_git_aliases () {
  local -a aliases; local al
  __git_extract_aliases
  for al in ${aliases%%:*}; do
    alias g$al="git $al"
  done
}
define_git_aliases
```

That's still a lot more effort that necessary, and potentially extra porting effort to cope with different versions of zsh. `__git_extract_aliases` is basically one line of code.

```sh
for al in ${${${(0)"$(git config -z --get-regexp '^alias.')"}%%$'\n'*}#alias.}; do
  alias g$al="git $al"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the second example. The one using `_git` and `__git_extract_aliases` didn't work, and I must admit that it took me a while to see the little _typo_ in the variable names (alias and al).

Comment: I gave another shot to the first example it worked! (variable names again, but now it was my mistake). Thank you again!